# JQuery - change attribute of asp object

Tags: jquery, .net, charts

How can I use jquery to set Chart1 to be visble?
The following code is what im trying but its fail.
Please help, thanks a lot

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function helloWorld() {
        $(document).ready(function () {
           $('#Chart1').attr("Visible", "true");
        })
    }
</script>

<asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server" Width="860px" Visible="false" onmouseover="helloWorld();" >
```

Answer (score 2):

By having the server side property `Visible`set to false, you're causing it to never be sent to the browser, client side code will be helpless.

First, change `Visible="false"` to: `style="display: none;"` then such code should work, assuming the final ID of the element will indeed be `Chart1`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#Chart1').show();
})
```

If no luck, check the HTML source code to know the actual ID and let me know, you'll have to use some sort of pattern lookup.

Comment: Ah - missed that one, but that is also correct. Client side visible=false will result in no html being produced. Which makes it even more difficult.

Comment: Do you mean that it is impossible to change the server side value of asp object such as the width or height of the chart?

Comment: Kelvin - that's not relevant. In the `.aspx` markup you can define the control properties. You can define height and width as usual, just don't have the `Visible="false"` as it will nuke any chance of manipulating the control in client side code.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is almost certainly that the ID is being uniquified by the ASP control, and so is no longer simply Chart1. There is also the likelihood that the control produces a set of html. So I would suggest you identify what the html being generated is, and write your javascript against these objects.